# Graphically represent SQL Data

Tags: sql, visualization

Given a table with the following structure with 11+M transactions.

```
ID     ProductKey    CloseDate   Part  PartAge Sales
1      XXXXP1        5/10/15      P1    13     100
2      XXXXP2        6/1/16       P1    0      15
3      XXXXP3        4/1/08       P1    0      280
4      XXXXP1        3/18/11      P1    0      10
5      XXXXP3        6/29/15      P1    45     15
6      XXXXP1        8/11/13      P1    30     360
```

Products XXXXP1 and XXXXP3 are entered twice since they are resales. Product Age=0 indicates its a new sale. So these products went from:

New Sale --> ReSale --> ReSale

Using a self-joining query, I can retrieve all the products which were resales. But is there a way to display these in a pretty graph or tree format?

Something which depicts the life-span of the sale transaction of the product?

Any ideas will be appreciated.

TIA,
B

Comment: What SQL and what language, software, etc. are you using to display?

Comment: SQL doesn't output to a graph, it just outputs result sets. Do you have visualization software to which you are feeding the results from the SQL?

Comment: I'd opt out for simplicity. Rather than develop a graph based display outside of SQL (which may be cumbersome to maintain) you can make the best use of the tabular format. For example you can order by product # and date and add an extra column with the type of transaction (using case when statements). You will be able to see the history of all products with the labels NewSale/Resale.

Comment: Thank you duncan - am using SQL Server for DB. Wondering what the appropriate viz tool I could use and format I could display the results in. Know there are quite a few in the market. JNevill I am aware that SQL doesnt output to a graph, so was wondering if there is an appropriate viz api which i could use for this case. Tudor Saru - thank you for the example